# IMX28 - Failed to send SELECT command

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, i2c, imx6

I'm working on the StarterKit-5 equipped with a Ka-Ro TX28 module.
Operating system is Linux (Yocto). 
Everything is working great so far, except the i2c0 bus.

When using the **i2cdetect -y 0** to scan a devices on the i2c bus,
the following message is displayed:

```
$ i2cdetect -y 0
...
mxs-i2c 80058000.i2c: PIO: Failed to send SELECT command!
...
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to do something you don't completely understand. 1. You have to understand how hardware is looked like from software prospective (what IPs are there, how they are sharing pins and so on). 2. You have to understand what pin control means and how pins under question are configured. 3. You have not to mangle I2C bus in racy manner (like doing some arbitrary stuff from user space on a bus which is used by some drivers in the kernel).

Comment: if you understand what I say?

Comment: I’m sure everything is connected correctly and the hardware is OK... But nevertheless I can work with it...